# Modx Articles (blog) href link for [[*pagetitle]] wont show on my web pages

Tags: content-management-system, blogs, modx

Below please find my article (individual blog) template for Modx.  Everything works fine except for the fact that my [[*pagetitle]] value is not visible.  I can select it with the mouse, but it is invisible.  I am using the default sample.ArticleRowTpl.  Also, find below my container template as well.  Does anyone know why it wont display the [[*pagetitle]] href?

```
Individual article blog template:
[[$blogHeader]]
```

[[$blogMenu]]


    
        Blog
        
        
            [[*pagetitle]]

```
        <p class="post-info">
            <span class="left">Posted on [[*publishedon:strtotime:date=`%b %d, %Y`]] by <a
                    href="[[~[[*parent]]]]author/[[*publishedby:userinfo=`username`]]">[[*publishedby:userinfo=`username`]]</a></span>
        </p>
        <br>

        <div class="entry">
            [[*content]]
        </div>

        <!--<hr />-->
        <p>
            [[*articlestags:notempty=`
            <br>
            <span class="tags left">&nbsp;<b style="color: #000000">Tags: </b>[[+article_tags]]</span>
            <br>
            `]]
        </p>
        <div class="post-comments" id="comments">
            <br>
            [[+comments]]
            <h3>Add a Comment</h3>
            [[+comments_form]]
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 verticalLine">
        <div class="sidemenu">
            <h3>Latest Posts</h3>
            <ul>
                [[+latest_posts]]
            </ul>
        </div>

        [[+comments_enabled:is=`1`:then=`
        <div class="sidemenu">
            <h3>Latest Comments</h3>
            <ul>
                [[+latest_comments]]
            </ul>
        </div>
        `]]
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end: .containter -->
```

[[$blogFooter]]

Blog container template

```
[[$blogHeader]]
```

[[$blogMenu]]


    
        Blog
        
        
            
            
                [[*content]]

```
    <div class="col-md-4 verticalLine">
        <div class="sidemenu">
            <h3>Latest Posts</h3>
            <ul>
                [[+latest_posts]]
            </ul>
        </div>

        [[+comments_enabled:is=`1`:then=`
        <div class="sidemenu">
            <h3>Latest Comments</h3>
            <ul>
                [[+latest_comments]]
            </ul>
        </div>
        `]]
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end: .containter -->
```

[[$blogFooter]]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Somehow I had a class in my .css file (which I wasnt actually using) that was causing this anomaly.  It took me a while to troubleshoot, but I finally figured out which one it was and removed it.  It works fine now:)